# How to translate title of `abstract` in a pandoc's markdown (e.g., Rmd) document?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

In the YAML header of a pandoc's markdown file, it's possible to write an abstract. I wonder if there is a way to change the word **"abstract"** in the rendered document to something else like either word "summary" or equivalent in another language.

If not, what alternatives could be suggested? I'm using R Markdown.

p.s. My question is related to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373961/how-to-include-an-abstract-in-a-rmakdown-rmd-file#comment69248380_36377313).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your main interest is in localization of your document, you can add an `lang` meta value to your document.  E.g., setting `lang: lt` will give "Santrauka" instead of "Abstract" in the produced PDF.

Comment: For PDF output, in addition to `lang: lt`, I had to include `header-includes:
  \usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}` into YAML header to get the word correctly translated to Lithuanian. Any ideas for HTML?

Comment: The default pandoc template for HTML doesn't include the abstract (should probably be changed). Using a custom template is probably your best bet in that case.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. But not automatically. You would have to redefine the `abstract` environment to start with a different header, or at least redefine the `\abstractname` variable as `article.cls` has this:

```
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname           %%%% This what you need to redefine
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
```

So you can do something like the following minimal example:

```
---
title: "Test Document"
author: "Some User"
output: pdf_document
abstract: >
  One or two sentences describing it all.
header-includes:
  \renewcommand{\abstractname}{My Very Own Summary}
---    

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document.
```

which does what you desire:

[image]

Comment: This solution works for PDF. Nice. And what about HTML: is there a solution?

Comment: "Probably". You will have to follow its code to its template use and alter / override there.

Comment: Ultimately, `rmarkdown` calls `pandoc` with a given template. You may have to modify that template, or write a new one. I am generally more concerned with pdf output.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML template now [includes the abstract](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/cbb33fefb758250e745d9795ce97cc91e293626a/data/templates/default.html5#L55-L60), and its heading can be customized using the [metadata variable](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#metadata-variables) `abstract-title`:

```yaml
---
title: A title
author: An author
abstract: >
  The abstract.
abstract-title: Summary
---
```

Notice that this only affects the HTML, EPUB, and docx writers, though.